# Domain name only works when adding Https, Node

Tags: express, https, dns

this is my first real problem with node. I have recently converted my website to https. This is great but my site can only be accessed by "https://www.example.com". Before converting I used port 80 (The default port), and basic express routing. I used to be able to connect to the ip address of my server and typing the domain name "www.example.com". I have the DNS set to redirect to the ip address of the server with ipv4 and ipv6. After switching to https I am no longer able to access the server using the ip address and the port 443 (I host on port 443). I am wanting to know why I can not access my website using the ip address + the port number (123.456.78.90:443) and why I must be so specific when getting at my website using https://www.example.com and not just www.example.com.

```
express = require('express');
app = express();

var http = require('https')
var fs = require('fs')

var sslPath = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.site/'

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(sslPath + 'privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(sslPath + 'fullchain.pem')
}

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

 app.get("/", function(req,res){
     console.log("Someone Connected")
     res.render("homepage");
});

server = http.createServer(options, app)
io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
server.listen(443)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no longer able to access", what exactly happens when you try `https://123.456.78.90:443`?

Comment: That was fast. When I say no longer able to access I cant type in the url "123.456.78.90:433" It says "Page isn't working, 123.456.78.90 did not send any data". I used to be able to when it was't https

Answer (score 3):

If your server only accepts `https`, then you HAVE to specify `https://` in the URL.  That's the only way the browser knows that is the protocol you intend to use.  When you leave out the `https://` from a URL in the url bar of the browser, the browser assumes `http`, no matter what port number you specify.

You could make your server respond to http on port 80 and automatically forward to https.  Then, you could type `www.example.com` in the browser and it would automatically redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

Your server will never respond to `123.456.78.90:443` which the browser will turn into `http://123.456.78.90:443` because on port 443, you're listening for `https` connections, not `http` connections (you can't listen for both on the same port).

Using the auto-redirect logic described about, you could type `123.456.78.90` into the browser and it would redirect to `https://123.456.78.90` which would work.

You can either implement the auto-redirect yourself (set up a simple http server listening on port 80 and redirect all incoming requests to the same URL, but with https in front of it).  Or, many hosting providers offer this feature built into their infrastructure (built into proxies or load balancers).

Comment: Thanks, looking into that.